# How can I take chat_id in job_queue run_repeating callback function in telegram bot in python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I need to take chat_id in repeating task to send users some repeating but personalized messages. How can I take chat_id in repeating func?

```
def repeating(context):

    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=<CHAT_ID>,text=res["message"])

def main():
    updater = Updater(constants.BOT_API_KEY, use_context= True)


    job_queue = JobQueue()
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    job_queue.set_dispatcher(dp)
    job_queue.run_repeating(callback=repeating,interval=5)


    updater.start_polling()
    job_queue.start()

    updater.idle()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods `JobQueue.run_*` have a parameter called `context` that can be used to pass information to the callback. In the callback, the contents of this parameter are available as `context.job.context`. Please have a look at

- [the docs](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html#telegram.ext.JobQueue.run_repeating) of `run_repeating`
- the [wiki page on `JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-JobQueue)
- [this example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/v13.x/examples#timerbotpy),

where the latter two showcase how to use the `context` parameter.

Also note that you should not manually instantiate a `JobQueue` - use `updater.job_queue` instead. Otherwise you'll also have to take care of actually starting and shutting down the `JobQueue`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Answer (score -1):

For me, the easiest way is to store those values in dict.
In code it should look like this:

```
updater = Updater(constants.BOT_API_KEY, use_context= True)
dp = updater.dispatcher

mailinglist={123:'personal message'} 
#you can use a list (mailinglist=[123,1234,...]), but there will be no personal messages

def mailing():
    for user_id in mailinglist: #mailinglist[user_id] gets personal message 
        bot.send_message(user_id, mailinglist[user_id])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    job_queue = JobQueue()
    job_queue.set_dispatcher(dp)
    job_queue.run_repeating(callback=mailing,interval=5)

    updater.idle()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is not the point in the question. I am asking for how to take user's chat_id information in a telegram bot.

Comment: What do you mean? You want to get the name and other info about user? If that is the case, bot api probably would not be able to help you, you should consider using self-bots (userbots) (this is because bots cant get user info by their id). Is that what you need?) If you just need to iterate through chat id's, my solution should work for you...